# Exercise 2.13 from a computational introduction to number theory and algebra

Tags: number-theory

This is an exercise from [V. Shoup. A computational introduction to number theory and algebra.](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fshoup.net%2Fntb%2Fntb-v2.pdf&ei=g4wvVav1EsjzasLbgZAH&usg=AFQjCNEtRfTiiD79uwmSET9YPGcO_KPBgg&sig2=nsskjUzrJZrTJqInVBB_tA)

[image]

Let $p=2, e=3, a=b=1, c = 0$, then $p^{2e} = 64, z\in \{0,1,2,\cdots,63\}$, the conclusion is, there are 8 numbers for the following to be true:
$$
\lfloor ((z+1) \mod 64) / 8 \rfloor = 0
$$

Well, there are only 7 such numbers, apparently, $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$.

Is there something wrong with my line of logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss $z=63$. For $z=63$, note that $z+1\equiv 0\pmod{64}$.